# Compiling module-info.java throws error: module not found

Tags: java, module, javac, java-11

I'm converting a simple application to java modules. I also need to make this application self contained with it's own custom JRE.  My application relies on multiple existing library jars that I am also converting to modular jars. To build a custom JRE I know that all code must be in modules. (You can't reference non-modular jars.  I found that out the hard way).

The problem is when I'm compiling the modules-info.java for one of the library jars that depends on another library jar (that I have already converted to modular).  It returns "error: module not found:jersey.core"

I've already updated one of the library jars by manually creating the module-info.java, compiling it and then updating the existing jar.

1). The file I created.

```
module jersey.core {
    exports com.sun.jersey.api.provider.jaxb;
    exports com.sun.jersey.api.representation;
    exports com.sun.jersey.api.uri;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.header;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.xml;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.osgi;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.provider;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.reflection;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ioc;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri;
    exports com.sun.jersey.core.util;
    exports com.sun.jersey.impl;
    exports com.sun.jersey.localization;
    exports com.sun.jersey.spi;
    exports com.sun.jersey.spi.inject;
    exports com.sun.jersey.spi.service;
    exports javax.ws.rs;
    exports javax.ws.rs.core;
    exports javax.ws.rs.ext;

    requires java.base;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires java.logging;
    requires java.xml;
}
```

2). Compiling

```
"%JDK11_HOME%/bin/javac" --patch-module jersey.core=../originaljars/jersey-core-1.13.jar module-info.java
```

3). Updating the jar

```
"%JDK11_HOME%/bin/jar" uf ../modules/jersey-core-1.13.jar -C jersey.core module-info.class
```

This was successful.

---

At first I tried creating the jersey.client module-info.java without a "depends on jersey.core".  Again, went through the same process of compiling and updating the jar but when I added the jar to my project Eclipse displayed the following error in MyTester.java.

```
The type javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  MyTester.java
```

This was thrown for a line where a WebResource object (comes from jersey.client) calls method webResource.type("application/json") which return a MediaType.

javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType comes from jersey.core.  So that lead me to believe jersey.client needs to require jersey.core.

I then decided to update the module-info.java for jersey.client
I added a requires jersey.core.

```
module jersey.client {
    exports com.sun.jersey.api.client;
    exports com.sun.jersey.api.client.async;
    exports com.sun.jersey.api.client.config;
    exports com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter;
    exports com.sun.jersey.client.impl;
    exports com.sun.jersey.client.impl.async;
    exports com.sun.jersey.client.osgi;
    exports com.sun.jersey.client.proxy;
    exports com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection;
    exports com.sun.ws.rs.ext;

    requires java.base;
    requires java.logging;
    requires jersey.core;
}
```

But when I try to compile this, I get the following error.

```
"%JDK11_HOME%/bin/javac" --patch-module jersey.client=../originaljars/jersey-client-1.13.jar module-info.java
module-info.java:15: error: module not found: jersey.core
requires jersey.core;
                   ^
1 error
```

Figured, the error was literally telling me it can't find the module, so I needed to tell it where my modules were located.

```
 "%JDK11_HOME%/bin/javac" --patch-module jersey.client=../originaljars/jersey-client-1.13.jar module-info.java -p ../modules
module-info.java:15: error: module not found: jersey.core
requires jersey.core;
                   ^
1 error
```

And then thought maybe I need to also add the module explicitly.  But that also didn't work.

```
"%JDK11_HOME%/bin/javac" --patch-module jersey.client=../originaljars/jersey-client-1.13.jar module-info.java -p ../modules --add-modules jersey.core
 module-info.java:15: error: module not found: jersey.core
 requires jersey.core;
                   ^
 1 error
```

I'm very new to Java Modules so undoubtedly I'm doing something stupid.  Apologies in advance :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns our I did do something stupid.

1). You do have to set the module path to your application modules.

2). You can't use relative links for the path.  I updated it to be a full path.

```
"%JDK11_HOME%/bin/javac" --patch-module jersey.client=../originaljars/jersey-client-1.13.jar module-info.java --module-path "C:{add your full path here}\modules"
```